# Custom content for Custom Post Type parent page?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm looking to set a static page as the parent for a custom post type. Right now the parent page is showing all archives for that custom post type.

For example `http://mysite.com/cpt` would show content from page ID 20.

Is this possible?

Edit: I created a new Page with the slug `/cpt`, it did not override the custom post type archive parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new template file named `archive-cpt.php`, where `cpt` is the slug of your CPT with the custom content and upload in your theme root.

More on [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display).